# Access parent folder files after htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /folder/subfolder1/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^folder/subfolder1/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
RewriteRule !^folder/subfolder1/ folder/subfolder1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

and I have my `index.html` in that `/folder/subfolder1/`.

I need to include some `.js` files in my `index.html`, but they are located in `folder/subfolder2`, so when trying to run the following code:

**index.html**:

```
...
<script src="../subfolder2/file1.js" > </script>
<script src="../subfolder2/file2.js" > </script>
...
```

I get errors because it says that it does not find `www.example.com/subfolder2/file1.js` and `www.example.com/subfolder2/file2.js` (status `404 Not Found`).

What is the correct way to access those files in `/folder/subfolder2/`? 
Do I need to change my `.htaccess`? If so, how can I make it work?

Thanks

Comment: When you are in index.html, what does the url bar say? Does it say www.example.com/folder/subfolder1/index.html, or does it say www.example.com/subfolder1/index.html? URL paths and folder paths are not the same, watch out for that.

Comment: @palako, well `index.html` is actually in `/folder/subfolder1/` that's why I made that `.htacces`, so that when typing `www.example.com` it does redirect to my `index.html`, so when browser accesses `www.example.com` it's actually accessing `www.example.com/folder/subfolder1/index.html` and in my URL bar I see just `www.example.com` and there I get those errors.

Comment: yes, that's exactly my point. Your file is inside folder/subfolder1 in the directory structure, but from the browser perspective, it's in /subfolder1/, it doesn't know about /folder. You are asking the browser to get out of subfolder1 by using .., and that takes it to the /subfolder2, but you don't have anything server side to rewrite /subfolder2 to /folder/subfolder2.

Comment: ok I get your point, so what rule could I add to make it work?

Comment: Before that, can I ask if all those rewrite conditions and rules are there for some other purpose? It looks like you could simply have your DocumentRoot for www.example.com set to /folder, and not need any of that. Your browser would not see the /folder part, but it will all be inside folder in your servers directory structure.

Comment: Yes that's just the purpose of those rules. I'm not expert so it is possible that I don't need all those rules. The important thing is that when accessing `www.example.com` it actually points to page in `www.example.com/folder/subfolder1/index.html` and let `index.html` have access to `www.example.com/folder/subfolder2/` files

Comment: You just need to set the DocumentRoot of your VirtualHost to the path to /folder in your disk then.

Comment: I'm sorry, how can I do that?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128565/discussion-between-frank-and-palako).